# Is it the right way to implements spring InitializingBean like this?

Tags: java, spring

I want to assign value for host and port field in class IdGenerator,which is the best way to achieve this?

Note:IdGenerator is best  not  be managed by spring,
the client class can call genId() as a static method.

```html
@Component
public  class IdGenerator implements InitializingBean{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IdGenerator.class);

    @Value("${vesta.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${vesta.port}")
    private Integer port;

    static VestaHttpClient client;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        Assert.hasText(host);
        Assert.notNull(port);

        LOGGER.info("about to initial IdGenerator.");
        try {
            client = new VestaHttpClient(host, port);
        }catch(Exception e){
            LOGGER.info("IdGenerator  initialize failed .");
            throw new RuntimeException("----------VestaHttpClient initialize failed--------");
        }
        LOGGER.info("IdGenerator was successfully initialized.");
    }

    public static String genId(){
        return client.genId()+"";
    }

}
```

Comment: what's the problem? You are injecting 2 fields and ...?

Comment: what do you mean "IdGenerator is best not managed by spring"... then what do you need InitializingBean for?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply build `VestaHttpClient` as a bean in a  `@Configuration` class, using a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to grab the property values and inject them into fields annotated with `@Value`.  Here is some code I mocked to describe my recommendation (it may require some adjustments):

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:example.properties")
public class MyConfiguration {


    @Value("${vesta.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${vesta.port}")
    private Integer port;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public VestaHttpClient get httpClient(){

        VestaHttpClient httpClient = null;

        try {
            client = new VestaHttpClient(host, port);
        }catch(Exception e){
        /*Omitted*/
        }
        return httpClient;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **inject** the property values using **field injection**, *so called “clean” configuration bean*, then `InitializingBean` is the right way to validate your properties.

However another way is to use just **constructor injection** and get rid of InitializingBean

```
@Component
public class IdGenerator {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IdGenerator.class);

    private String host;

    private Integer port;

    static VestaHttpClient client;

    @Autowired
    public WebProperties(@Value("${vesta.host}") String protocol,
                         @Value("${vesta.port}") Integer port) {
        // Validate properties and initialize VestaHttpClient
    }
}
```